# how to use IGNORE?

Tags: mysql

i have mysql code for input data:

```
 $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO inspection_report ";
  $sql.= "(Model,       Serial_number,       Line,        Shift,     Inspection_datetime,         Range_sampling,       Packing, ";
  $sql.= "Accesories,       Appearance,      Tuner,        General_operation,       Class,      Status,         Remark, ";
  $sql.= "NIK) ";
  $sql.= "VALUES ('";
  $sql.= $Model."','".$Serial_number."', '".$Line."','".$Shift."','".postVar('insp_date')." ".postVar('time')."','".$Range_sampling."','".$Packing."','";
  $sql.= $Accesories."','".$Appearance."','".$Tuner."','".$General_operation."','".$Class."','".$Status."','".$Remark."','";
  $sql.= $NIK."')";
```

i want to use IGNORE.but how to prevent duplicate only at Model,Serial_number,Line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

[INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors
>   that occur while executing the INSERT
>   statement are treated as warnings
>   instead. **For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an
>   existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a
>   duplicate-key error and the statement
>   is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still
>   is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued.**

So that tells me that either `Model,Serial_number,Line` must be the Primary key, or you need to create an Unique index on these columns.

Comment: should i change the Model,Serial_number,Line become Unique index?

Comment: If Model, Serial_Number, Line is not already your table Primary Key, then yes, you need to create an Unique index for these columns.